# Warning on char or int or short or long or unsigned

Tags: c, c11

Since it seems we should avoid `char` or `int` or `short` or `long` or `unsigned`.

"If you find yourself typing char or int or short or long or unsigned into new code, you're doing it wrong", from https://matt.sh/howto-c.

Is it possible to instruct compiler to warn on this cases?

Comment: Ok, since my comment was removed because of the BS word, I will repeat: This article is this word. The sentence servicing the premise to this question is highly controversial.

Comment: Note that there's a section: _One Exception to never-char

The only acceptable use of char in 2016 is if a pre-existing API requires char (e.g. strncat, printf'ing "%s", ...) or if you're initializing a read-only string (e.g. const char *hello = "hello";) because the C type of string literals ("hello") is char [].

ALSO: In C11 we have native unicode support, and the type of UTF-8 string literals is still char [] even for multibyte sequences like const char *abcgrr = u8"abc";._   Unfortunately, the C standard library is written in terms of `char` and `char *` — and most programs use it!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The main problem is that the C standard is providing different definitions and guarantees for the"built-in" types, while it is not the case for `stdint` types.

Comment: Wow, a blog article about C which is actually containing good, sound advise. That's a rare thing on the internet. I don't know who the author is but he knows what he's talking about.

Comment: @EugeneSh. There's nothing controversial with avoiding those types. They have numerous known flaws, they are completely non-portable and we have known this since the early 90s. That's why stdint.h was invented in the first place. C99, C11, MISRA-C and so on, all agree that these types are bad and are only allowed to exist for the sake of backwards-compatibility.

Comment: @Lundin No, not all agree. There are use cases for fixed-width types, and there are usecases for "abstract" numerical types. When I want to store a character, *I don't care* how many bits it is going to consume. When I want to do a simple math on integers, or have a counter,  *I don't care* how many bits these integers will be as long as I have `limits.h` around.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Using `char` for storing characters is the only valid use of that type too. But if you don't care how many bits the integers in your arithmetic use, then you are writing a minefield of lurking, subtle bugs. C is neither forgiving nor rational here - it will shoot you down with overflows and implicit type promotions unless you know exactly how large your types are and how the types are silently changed by your code. If you don't want to know, don't code in C. There's multiple other languages far more suitable for those who don't want to know the dirty details.

Comment: @Lundin The overflow case can be very well managed using the limits values of the types in many cases. I am not saying fixed-width types are useless - not at all. I am working with them most of the time in embedded development, but again. C is defined in terms of `char`s, `int`s and `long`s. `%d` will print `int` and not `int32_t`. And no, not all of the compilers have format specifier for `int32_t`. `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, but not `sizeof(uint8_t)`. And many more examples.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The Standard would also allow a compiler to assume that a `uint8_t*` will never be used to access anything that isn't of type `uint8_t` or `int8_t`.  Of course, a *quality* compiler should recognize situations where a `uint8_t*` is derived from something of another type and used to access the storage, at least until the next time the storage is accessed via other means whether or not the Standard requires it, but that would be equally true of any other pointer type.  As it is, though, the Standard offers dispensation only for actual character types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to make the compiler warn about it. There might be code analyzing tools that can.

To "avoid them" on a general basis is a bit harsh. `char` is guaranteed being a single byte, is used for text even in C11, and the standard libraries often use the platform dependent types, e.g. `int` as the return value of `strcmp`.

Comment: Refereces to code analyzing tools might be helpful.

Comment: @KcFnMi Agreed, but I don't have any personal experience working with such tools. Feel free to suggest any you know of (edit the post or add comment).

Answer (score 1):

A compiler will never warn against it, because the compiler's job is to check against language compliance and those types are perfectly fine as far as the language standard is concerned.

If you need a tool that warns against using dangerous types, you could get a MISRA-C checker. The MISRA-C guidelines are used to create a safe subset out of the unsafe C language. Among other things, MISRA does not allow the use of the mentioned types, but instead insists that only the types from `stdint.h` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Many language constructs are defined in terms of the built-in types.  Code which uses abstract types other than character types should be written to work equally well if larger types were substituted, and code which relies upon abstract types being larger than the minimum sizes given in the Standard, and which anyone might try to run on systems where they aren't, should check to ensure that the sizes are as required.  Note that it doesn't matter whether code actually declares any objects of the abstract sizes.

For example, given `int16_t x; uint16_t y;` the behavior of `(0xC000+x > 49152-y)` will be affected by the size of `int`.  If `int` is 32 bits, then the computations and comparisons will be performed using signed values.   If `int` is 16 bits, however, the left operand will be evaluated as a 16-bit unsigned value then promoted to long, for comparison with the right-hand side which will be evaluated as a signed long.

While it would be convenient to write code that could be agnostic with regard to the sizes of abstract types, merely pretending that such types don't exist won't achieve that.